# Dynamically change table data in Partial view MVC based on dynamic drop down list selection

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, partial-views

A drop down list is generating by a rest service response and not sure how many options will be there. Now based on drop down selection table data needs to be changed.
I am working on a MVC web application which calls rest service to pull dropdown list and another rest service to populate data in html table using partial view based on user selection.
What I am trying is here
In the ASCX page

```
 <div class="divRightColumnSection">
            <br/> <%Response.Write(Model.DisplayData());%>           
 </div>
```

In the java script

```
$(document).on('change', '#MMC', function () {
var indexSelected = $("#MMC").prop('selectedIndex');
//var valueSelected = this.value;
$.ajax({
    url: "/your-equip-add/address/" + indexSelected + "/",
    type: "POST",
    cache: "false",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{value: "' + $("#indexSelected").val() + '" }',
});
```

});

C# controller

```
public void GetSelected(string value)
        {
            YourModel model = new YourModel ();
            BaseModel bModel = new BaseModel();
            model.indexSelected = Int32.Parse(value);
            bModel.DisplayData();      
        }
```

C# basemodel 
DropDown is list which is drop down list data

```
for(int i=0;i<DropDown.Count;i++)
            {
                SDropDown.Add(new SForDropDown()
                { Md = Ged(DropDown[i].EModel),
                Don=PSis(DropDown[i].Eac),
                Peed= Pion(DropDown[i].Eac)});          
            }
```

C# HTML What i am trying is

```
 toReturn = " <style>table { width:90%;} table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}th, td {padding: 3px;text-align: left;font-weight: bold;}}</style><h2>MMC result </h2><table>" +
                   "<tr><td colspan=3  height=40>" +
                   "<Select id=\"MMC\" name=\"MMC\" >";
                foreach (DropDownModel Item in objectUnite.DropDown)
                {
                    toReturn += "<option value=\"" + Item.EModel+"|"+Item.EMac + "\"";
                    if (index == 0)
                        toReturn += " selected=\"true\"";
                    toReturn += ">" + Item.EModel+"|"+ Item.EpMac + "</option>";

                    index++;
                }

                toReturn += "</Select></td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td>MD</td><td>" + objectUnite.MD + "</td></tr>" +                      
                    "<tr><td>PEED</td><td>" + objectUnite.PEED + "</td></tr>" +                       
                    "<tr><td></td><td>DON</td><td>" + objectUnite.DON + "</td></tr>" +
                    "</table>";
```

The data what I am displaying in HTMl needs help to be changed based on dropdown index selection.
Any suggestion please